# Using Material-UI how does one resize the rows of a grid component with direction = column?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a material-ui page layout using grid and direction=column.  The 'height' of the rows is too big.  I can't find any info at all on how to make the rows thinner.  I've tried using a smaller font but that just makes the text smaller.

Here's the code:

'''

```
  <Grid container direction='column'>
    <Grid item name='PageHeader'>
      <NavMenu />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item name='PageBreadcrumb'>
      <Breadcrumb />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item container name = 'PageContent'>

        {this.props.children}

    </Grid>
    <Grid item name='PageFooter'>
    <Footer />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

'''

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you please attach an image to show the issue? Normally, you can use ````maxHeight```` property in json based styling or  ````max-height```` of css property to accomplish such task.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Like with an example?  I can add a screen shot, but it's just going to show a page with a header row, content, and a footer row.  The row heights of all the 'columns' (which is confusing since we're talking vertically and the 'columns' are actually rows) is too big.

Comment: How do I add a screenshot?  I see no way to do this.

Comment: And I'm trying not to use css and affect the html directly.  I want to do it the material-ui way.

Comment: I presume you want header and footer to be smaller. What components are you using for those elements? You can style them from within the JS. Can you provide a CodeSandbox? I think that easiest way to fix this would be to reduce line-height.

Comment: I'm using material-ui components built in as is shown above.  You're not supposed to use direct css, but something prefaced with mui instead.  Anyone know material-ui around here who can help?

Comment: Radule, I am using material-ui components as I've specified above.  The ONLY code available is what you see above.  So, if what you say is true, can you give a specific example using the above code?  Everyone keeps asking me what components I'm using, when it's clearly shown above in the code.  I'm using the Grid component.  direction = column.